# How to add existing node to another node with different parent as a Reference with Firebase and Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a tree of data that consists of multiple Parents and Childs, but I want to add a child node to another parent node as a reference so that every time I update the child node the another child node (with a different parent) will be updated too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, it is impossible. You can try to set to parent nodes keys 
(id) of child nodes.